# Enforce Ownership Hierarchy Java

Tags: java, architecture, access-control

Is it possible, for instance using annotations, to create a kind of 'hierarchy' of ownership of a class?

As an example, suppose there are three levels of objects in this "hierarchy", `Level1`, `Level2`, and `Level3`.

`Level1` can own (in my case, as a Spring `@Autowire` instance variable) an instance of `Level2` but cannot own `Level3` (because it is two levels deep). In addition, *only* `Level1` classes can own `Level2`. Similarly, `Level3` can only be owned by `Level2`.

I am very curious to see if some combination of annotations, and compilation-time arguments could be used to achieve the result.

*Note.* I am looking for answers that correspond specifically to what I described. But the specific use case (if it helps) is preventing high level business logic from calling database repositories directly, or for instance API controllers calling lower-level services directly when they are intended to only call high-level business logic.

This question, at its core, is about a generalisation of the access-control (`private, protected...`) to arbitrary package structures, through annotations for example.

Comment: Normally you would do that using dependencies. "Level1" depends on "Level2" and "Level3", but not the other way around. This will enforce that you can't use anything from "Level1" in "Level2".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn my problem with that is that it does not enforce that you can only use your direct inferior - i.e., it doesn't prevent 1 calling 3. In addition, it requires creating packages that mess up the project structure we're working with.